# Is it possible to set Facebook app to share to "public" automatically instead of having my user select public in the pull-down menu?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook app that I created which is integrated with my website to let customers share their purchases.  However, I see that the customer has to set the pull-down menu to "public" each time.

Is there a way to set "public" as the default selection when sharing through my Facebook app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, it´s not possible. The user should always be able to decide how he shared stuff, so it would be a very bad thing to force him anyway.

Setting the privacy is only possible with the feed API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed#publish

...although, you would need to authorize the user with `publish_actions`, and you will definitely not get it approved for that.